# Exploration of specific groups (21,⊗21).

Tags: finite-groups, cryptography

Consider the Group (21,⊗21).
a) Determine the order of this Group.
b) List the complete set of elements of this Group.
c) Construct the Cayley table of the Group.
d) Determine if two distinct subgroups have the same order.
The Group (Un,⊗n):
For a positive integer n and a and b elements of Un, define

```
                    a ⊗n b := (a * b) mod n.
```

my answer is:
List of element of G = [1, 11, 16, 17, 8, 19, 2, 13, 4, 5, 10, 20]
Order of the Group =  12
I wrote down the Cayley table too.

### ***I need help with item d) about the subgroups***.

Any help would be great.
Please let me know if the elements of the Group are correct?

Comment: You are correct about the order of the group and all the elements you listed are coprime to 21 so your answer is correct. As for (d), what have you tried? Do you have a guess? Are you familiar with Lagrange's theorem or the Chinese Remainder theorem (and how it applies here)? Have you found the orders of the elements, for example? Do you see how finding the orders of the elements might help?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Hello, yes, I am familiar with Lagrange's theorem. No, I haven't the order of elements. I know that for |G| = 12, the only possible orders for a subgroup are 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, and 12. is it the answer?

Comment: @runway44   Thanks for the leads. I have found the solution, wants to make sure it is correct :    If there are any subgroups their sizes must divide 12 So the possible subgroup
can be 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12
Size 12 –> all of G
Size 1 —> H = {id=1}
size 2 subgroup the second number should be inverse itself, for (13*13) mod
21 = 1 and (20*20) mod 21 =1
size 2 —> H = {1,13}
size 2 —> H = {1,20}
for subgroup of size 2 we have two distinct subgroups with the same order.
Size 3 —> H = {1,13,20}